# How to check user input that's being posted to the same page

Tags: php, html, validation

So I have a html form that's posting to the same page using PHP.. which is cool, but in order to stop PHP from throwing errors every time the page is opened, if added a system that checks to see if the post variable is empty (which it is when the user first loads the page since they havent had chance to input anything). My question is, is there a better way of doing this? Because the PHP script is loaded when the form is loaded, i get the message "You havent typed anything". I dont want this too appear when the page first loads, only when it's necessary..

Here's the code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table align="center">
<tr> 
    <td>Enter a word to hash:  </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="input" size="20" maxlength="20"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Hash"> </td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>

<?php
if(empty($_POST['input']))
{
    echo 'You didnt type anything!';
    exit;
}

$input = $_POST['input'];
$input=trim($input);
    echo md5($input);

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, check the [`REQUEST_METHOD`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST['input']) ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man.. I put the error message in there.. but because the $input = $_POST['input'] was outside, it still tried to initialize it when the page was loaded.. but now i know about the Server Request value, i changed your code so it was:

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    empty($_POST['input']) )
    {
        error
    }

    rest of code
}

Answer (score 1):

`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST['input']))`

Answer (score 1):

Try `isset` either than `empty`, because on the first page load `$_POST['input']` should not exist.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input']) && empty($_POST['input']) )
{
    echo 'You didnt type anything!';
    exit;
} else {
//check
}

?>
```

Comment: But doesnt empty() achieve the same as isset()?

I mean, isset checks if it exists, and empty checks if it exists, and if it has a NONZERO value.. so wouldnt it be the same outcome?

Comment: `empty` on a non existant variable throws a php NOTICE so no it isn't the same ;) see [docs](http://php.net/empty) !

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want:

- Always show the form
- Print the MD5 hash if someone submitted the form

You can accomplish it like this. It says if there is a POST value with the key **input** then trim any leading and trailing whitespace and print the MD5 hash of that value.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['input']))
{
    echo md5(trim($_POST['input']));
}

?>
```